# Stream audio to Windows 10 through USB

Tags: usb, audio, windows, streaming

I want to listen to the podcasts I have on my Android phone while I'm playing games on my computer and therefore, I want to stream the audio from my phone to my Windows 10 computer.

I'm wondering if it's possible to do that through USB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you probably can route audio to USB (I assume if you connect a USB device that identifies it as a USB audio receiver... thingy) your PC is a USB host.

So a better solution would be to get a [USB audio adapter like this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS) (may not be necessary if you have a mic in port), connect your headphone into the mic, and [get something like VLC to play it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12277592/975887).

Windows also allows to "Listen" to an input device which plays it out of your speakers so you don't *need* VLC or a special player.  (See image below). Note that this can be annoying if you do video conferencing as you will have to make sure this is disabled when you're on a call.

[image: Windows listen to device options]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) and your Android audio goes through your PC by default.

> This application mirrors Android devices (video and audio) connected via USB or over TCP/IP