# Streaming audio to windows10 through USB

Tags: audio, headphones, streaming

I want to listen music from my android device (Xiaomi Redmi Note 7).
I checked this page that tell you maybe the best option to do that.
[Stream audio to windows10 through USB](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/156389/stream-audio-to-windows10-through-usb)

But the issue is that when i plug the aux cable into my phone, it recognize it like an headphone. And after i plug the cable into mic port into pc it doesn't recognize it like an headphone anymore.
If i play an audio just in that second when i connect it to pc it work, after changing song my phone doesn't regonize it like an headphone again.

Comment: Does it work at all at least for a short time? If yes does the audio play in stereo? An alternative way to transmit audio to the PC would be to use Bluetooth. Theoretically this should also work.

Comment: You should get an external digital-to-analog converter (DAC) and an appropriate amplifier for your headphones and/or speakers. That will provide far better sound quality than the headphone jack on your phone or Bluetooth.